# Debian test if load average shows real value

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, load, debian

How can I test that my kernel is showing the correct load average ?
The load is always high on this server, and I doubt it's the real one.
I use kernel 3.2.0

```
Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.53-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and Debian version 7.3

Comment: what does `top` show? also this question fits more in SuperUser forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning get more info directly from kernel, then it's better to look at /proc/sched_debug (this requires, SCHED_DEBUG=y), then you can look for load related info in there. They basically export various runqueues fields like. load, # of running tasks, load stat via cpu_load[] and many more. Interpreting those field might require some inside knowledge of Linux scheduler.

To keep things straight, you can do:

```
      cat /proc/sched_debug|grep -w load
```

This will give you all the load related info. If possible write a script or program to parse the required fields for better interpretation. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can find load average by executing following commands

```
uptime
top
cat /proc/loadavg
```

Comment: Nice commands, but i wanted to know more in depth, something from kernel. I am making a diagnose to the kernel.Ty anyway